# Javascript redirect infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html

Chrome is not redirecting to an intranet site. The body onload method is looping infinitely. If I change the target to an external website such as google.com, the redirection works. Can someone give pointers to find why is there an infinite loop for my intranet site?

Below is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script type="text/javascript" src="openBrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openURL(){
    var targetURL="http://myintranetsite";
    openBrowser(targetURL);
}
</script>

<BODY onLoad="openURL()">
    <div id="loadBrowser"><h1>Opening Browser..</h1></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

my javascript

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if(isChrome)
    {
        //Changes the URL to destination if the current chrome browser version is 40
        if(getChromeVersion()>=40)
        {               
            window.location=targetURL;                                              
        }
}
```

Comment: Well it looks to me that you redirect constantly to the same page?

Comment: well if you keep running the code and loop back, of course it will loop

Comment: What is the `openBrowser` function? Is this the page you're redirecting *to*, or redirecting *from*? If all of this is one page, then I don't know what you expect. The first thing you do when the page loads is check the Chrome Version and redirect them. Then it checks again, and redirects again. Forever.

Comment: where is the code that you've posted hosted? If it's hosted at http://myintranetsite then obviously there will be an infinite refresh (it's not an infinite loop, because every time `window.location` runs it will refresh the page. But if it's pointing to the same page, then it will do an infinite refresh. If you want this to work, the two pages (this one, and the one you are redirecting to) have to be hosted at different URLs

Comment: @Santi, the openBrowser function contains the javascript code which I posted and other functions to check IE, chrome versions.

Comment: @ADyson, the calling page and the called page are hosted at different URLs. Please see, the redirect works fine for IE browsers. The problem is only with chrome. Also, redirect works fine for external websites but not my intranet site

Comment: I am not seeing any redirect code for IE, only for Chrome? Where is the IE redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Check that window.location isn't your intranet page

```
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("myintranetsite") > -1) {
    openBrowser(targetURL);
}
```

Alternatively maybe hit the brakes a little later:

```
if (window.location.toString() != targetURL && getChromeVersion()>=40) {               
    window.location=targetURL;                                              
}
```

Comment: @kunaguvarun sorry about that - I made an edit earlier and only did half the job.  Try that

Comment: ok, this stops the infinite refresh and passing the control to my custom error handling section, which means that URL is not getting updated. Any way to completely clear out the existing URL and redirect to the new one?

Comment: @kunaguvarun yeah, you set window.location like is in the code you pasted above.  Just not to the same thing it already is.

Answer (score 0):

your code must be redirecting for chrome version 40 or higher, you must see that you are not already in the place where you want to go, causing infinite redirection. Here is the code that can work for you

```
  var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
  if(isChrome)
  {
          //Changes the URL to destination if the current chrome browser version is 40
          if(getChromeVersion()>=40 && window.location!==targetURL)
          {               
              window.location=targetURL;                                              
          }
  }
```

Comment: what does openBrowser() do ?
also can you console.log values of window.location and targetURL ?

Comment: openBrowser() will identify the browser and its versions. Ok, actually my IE redirection is a cheat. I'm launching a new IE window to load the new URL. If I use redirect as for Chrome, it refreshes infinitely as well